# Create bash script that can import variable and execute code against variable from external text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file that contains all the hostnames on my network of PCs that are not in use. I am creating a maintenance script that will run in the morning to restart the machines.

I have tried some code that will SSH to a machine and restart it, however I can only do this manually.

The code to reboot the machine is `ssh hostname echo "password" | sudo -S reboot`

I have created a bash script and tested the variable to ensure it is outputting the hostnames line by line which it does. But when I put that line of code as below it does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/hostnames.txt"
while IFS= read -r ipaddress
do
 ssh "$ipaddress" echo "password | sudo -S reboot"
done <"$file"
```

I would like the code to go one by one and apply that command to restart the machines as it can do that if I do the command manually. However I receive a error

```
Line 7 Unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'
Line 8 Syntax Error: Unexpected End of File.
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT - Realised I missed a '**"**' in the ssh command.

Comment: The ssh command in your text doesn't match the one in your codeblock although it will do the same thing. Presumably your password is not literally `password`. Are you sure you are escaping it correctly? Your error talks about line 8 but your codeblock only has 6 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake seems to be in the `ssh` command you are executing.

The way to execute a remote command would then be:

```
ssh [user]@$ipaddress "echo $password | sudo -S reboot"
```

You can omit the `[user]` when you are login in on the same username that you are using locally. Also make sure the `$password` variable is set somewhere in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/hostnames.txt"
user="my-server"
password="my-secret" 

while IFS= read -r ipaddress
do
 ssh "$user@$ipaddress" "echo $password | sudo -S reboot"
done <"$file"
```

And in fact you probably should not store your password in the script, so you might want to add a password prompt like so:

```
echo -n Password: 
read -s password
echo
# Run Command
# ...
```

Putting this together will get you:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/ubuntu/Desktop/hostnames.txt"
user="my-server"

echo -n Password: 
read -s password
echo

# Run Command
while IFS= read -r ipaddress
do
 ssh "$user@$ipaddress" "echo $password | sudo -S reboot"
done <"$file"
```

Comment: that looks good thanks for that. And if I wanted to add if statement on the reboot ssh command as some machines are windows (with cygwin environemnt) so the command to reboot is shutdown -r -t 0 how could i do that? Much appreciated the help